# Do all CPU that formally respect dependency allow independent dependencies?

Tags: c++, dependencies, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, stdatomic

The context of the question is normal cached memory such as the memory of C and C++ objects.

Many CPU perform memory loads out of order (with the benefit of not completely stalling the executing thread on a cache miss), and do not check later that another core did not ask the permission to change these (*), so a read that appears later in the program order was effectively retrieved earlier, and another thread might have made progress in that interval, which means that no agreement on the ordering of memory operations is possible between these two threads that agrees with program order.

(*) By asking the local cache to invalidate the cache line containing it, which is a prerequisite before altering a value in any architecture that can support normal thread programming.

Many CPU types that allow that behavior also guarantee that when a value depends on the result of previous load, all subsequent operations that have a dependency on that value occur really after the load, in particular the loads at an address derived from that value.

But a value derived from another can be known to be mathematically independent of the parameter; indeed, a common idiom to set a register to zero is to xor its value with itself, which syntactically derives the value from the previous one but semantically does not.

Do all CPU that track value dependencies to guarantee that memory operations based on values dependent on a previous load allow such non semantic dependencies to create an *independent dependency* for the purpose of ordering memory operations? Does that apply to bitwise operations or all arithmetic operations, including but not limited to use of absorbing elements?

Most obvious examples are:

- `x ^ x`
- `x & 0`
- `x | -1`
- `x - x`
- `x * 0`
- `x / x` (raises an exception if zero)

The purpose the question obviously is to understand how a compiler can support `memory_order_consume` in C and C++ on these architectures in an optimal way, following the intent of that feature (and not in a degenerate way by defining mo_consume as mo_acquire).

PROBLEM STATEMENT

The problem is the compilation of code such as

```
r1 = x.load(memory_order_consume);
r2 = y | (r1&0);
r3 = z + (r1-r1);
r4 = (&E)[r1*0];
```

Where the simple strategy of renaming `r1` and making it "register volatile" (volatile-like, non optimizable, except in a register) in the intermediate code produces correct "consume" (value/address dependent load) behavior on each operations.

BONUS QUESTION

Do any CPU directly support dependent constants? That is a "set immediate value" instruction that introduces an explicit dependency of the constant on a register value:

```
load.i.dep r1,8,r4 ; sets r1 to 8 but dependency on value of r4 is respected
lea r0,r0,r1       ; r0 += r1, r0 depends on r4
load.w r2,r1       ; loads one word at r1 to r2 only after r4 is known
```

Comment: A straightforward answer to the main question is No. Even Intel's CPU don't support all the possible dependency breaking operations. That's why there exist *idioms* (i.e. preferred ways to do things). It's likely that a "smaller" design doesn't support any dependency breaking operation at all. As with the bonus question, it's usually easy to create a dependency on a register (i.e. by setting it to an identity value like 0 or 1), specially if the answer of before is No. That would be too specific purpose.

Comment: @MargaretBloom You seem to misinterpret my question, maybe I should have included an example. I want to see if naive non-optimized compilation of consume order is valid in C++ in all cases, even such code as `(&E)[x.load(mo_consume)*0]`. Intel doesn't even have the consume/acquire distinction as no acquire barrier is needed, so a compiler cannot mis-compile a consume operation on Intel.

Comment: I think one of the main dangers is that compilers can sometimes transform data dependencies into *control* dependencies (that are subject to branch prediction + speculative execution without waiting for the input to the branch).  e.g. if a load is inside an `if` that allows the compiler to infer that a pointer value is equal to something else, it might break / omit the data dependency.

Comment: Also, you're using "non-optimizing" to mean something much stronger than `gcc -O0`:  they still transform your program through their internal representations, so especially gcc will have some "optimizations" within the evaluation of one expression.  e.g. `r1 - r1` won't actually compile to a runtime subtraction because even at `-O0` gcc knows that's just zero.  https://godbolt.org/z/ATYpWd shows an example: `a + (b-b)` compiles with no `sub` instruction for gcc.  clang and MSVC are "more literal" at -O0 though, but ICC only uses SUB on the stack pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes So there is no way to force to make a variable for register and volatile in intermediate code?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You can use `asm("": "+r"(var));` to make the compiler "forget" about the value, e.g. `int tmp=r1;` and then use `asm` to make it "forget" that `tmp=r1`.  But at that point it would be much easier (but arch-specific) to do `asm("and %0,  #0" : "+r"(var_to_zero));` to do the zeroing with inline asm.  (That's ARM / AArch64 syntax)

Comment: @curiousguy Oh, sorry. You comment cleared it up. If I may, you may want to add some punctuation to the periods. It's a bit hard to parse for non natives. I'm still a bit confused if you are asking about the CPU behaviour or the C++. [At least for the PPC case](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/ppc-supplemental/test7.pdf), the CPU considers the fourth case (the only  one with an addr-dependency?) dependent (I suspect this is a general approach). At the C++ level, all have *carry a dependency* with `r1` (as per section $1.10.9).

Comment: @MargaretBloom "_all have carry a dependency_" exactly! ...so all the expression need to be compiled 1) extremely naively (not just low optimization; no optimization at all) 2) does literal asm translation guarantee the preservation of the dependency on the value of r1? _Do CPU designers guarantee that they will **not** optimize trivial arithmetic operations (like `xor r1,r1`) in the future and kill the dependency?_ This isn't a question of what they do now but of what they promise.

Comment: @MargaretBloom "_I'm still a bit confused if you are asking about the CPU behaviour or the C++_" The focus is the potential difficulties in compiling such code, so I want to learn about the potential for a CPU to "optimize" very naively compiled code that has "dependent" constants in the form of `x-x` or `x/x` where `x` has a dependency on a load, for those CPU that promise to respect dependencies. (A modern CPU essentially translates at run time the binary code to a low level parallel execution workflow.)

Comment: At the other end of the spectrum, Intel promises that loads have acquire semantics so dependencies are tracked for the sole purpose of optimizing the translation of binary code to better workflow. It's a good thing when trivial (non-dependent) "dependencies" (typically `x^x`) are removed from the dependency graph; it can't break programs: **acquire is strictly stronger than consume**. (Whether CPU that do acquire remove these dependencies could be another, almost symmetrical question.)

Comment: @curiousguy The link I gave is answering you: PowerPC won't optimise away a dependency, even if it doesn't contribute to the final value of the address. [ARM is exactly the same](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHHIAEC.html). It's up to the programmer to break the dependency. But such dependency must first make it in the code, for C++11 `x-x` **is** a dependency. [GCC seems to take the heavy approach by lifting mo_consumer to mo_acquire and optimise `x-x` away](https://preshing.com/20141124/fixing-gccs-implementation-of-memory_order_consume/)

Comment: @MargaretBloom The Q is about whether it's a general property of CPU design that can be relied on by a PL designer when the specification of a consume operation is written.

Comment: @curiousguy It definitively not a general property but then either the CPU has another mechanism to enforce order (e.g. general memory barrier) or it is not suited for MP. In fact, this inability to generalise is true for every CPU property and it forces the PL to be defined abstractly or to be non portable. You define a consume operation pretty much like in C++ (requiring what is needed to work in the weakest model) and let the implementation (i.e. the compiler) deal with possible optimisations (i.e. recognising where an expression is still needed due to the presence of a consume load).